# Crystal Report simple count subquery

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

im trying to do this report in Crystal Reports 10:

I have this tables, ALUMN and COURSE:

```
COURSE_ID       COURSE_NAME
1               History
2               Biology
3               French

ALUMN_ID    ALUMN_COURSE    ALUMN_STATUS
1           1               ENROLLED
2           1               ENROLLED
3           1               PENDING
4           2               ENROLLED
5           2               PENDING
6           2               PENDING
7           3               ENROLLED
8           3               PENDING
```

And i want my Crystal Report to look like this:

```
COURSE_NAME     ENROLLED    PENDING 
History         2           1       
Biology         1           2       
French          1           1
```

In ORACLE SQL I do something like this, but i don't know how to do the same in a CR report:

```
SELECT ALUMN_COURSE, COURSE_NAME
COUNT(CASE WHEN ALUMN_STATUS='ENROLLED' THEN 1 END) AS ENROLLED,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ALUMN_STATUS='PENDING' THEN 1 END) AS ELIMINADOS,
FROM ALUMN JOIN COURSE ON ALUMNO_COURSE=COURSE_ID
GROUP BY ALUMNO_COURSE, COURSE_NAME;
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula {@Enrolled_1_0} :

```
IF ALUMN_STATUS = "ENROLLED" Then 1 Else 0
```

Then, simply SUM that formula.

Similar logic for PENDING.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried this but I get the total enrolled for all courses, not for each course. I'm trying to do it with running fields and diferent combinations but I cant achieve the enrolled or pending for each course.

Comment: You need to Group by Course to allow Summing by Course.